# delete multiple selected items from the list angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to delete the one or more selected items in the list in angular js.

I tried to add the items in the following way:

```
$scope.selectedNodes = [];

$scope.addItem = function(e) {
 $scope.selectedNodes.push({
                id :$scope.selectedNodes.length + 1,
                Nodeid: e.item.id,
                title: e.item.text});            
            $scope.$apply();
        }
```

html is as below:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple ng-multiple="true">
                                <option ng-repeat="node in selectedNodes" value="{{node}}">{{node}}</option>
                            </select>
                            <button ng-click="remove(selectedItems)" type="submit">
                                Remove
                            </button>
```

The above html is listing fine with all the items.

Now I am trying to delete one or more items from the list, so the code I have written is:

```
  $scope.remove = function (nodes) {   
        alert(nodes); // it's giving the selected records info, no problem with it
        angular.forEach(nodes, function (node) {                       
            var index = $scope.selectedNodes.indexOf(node);            
            alert(index) //problem here, it's always -1
            $scope.selectedNodes.splice(index, 1);
        });
    };
```

The above code is removing the last item if one item is selected. And if more than one is selected, let's say two,  it's then removing  the last two records.
The index value is always -1 for any no. of iterations in the foreach loop.
Could anyone please help with the above code to delete one or more selected records and the list should get refreshed. No problem with refreshing for the above code.

I tried as you mentioned below, but no luck.

```
$scope.remove = function (nodes) {
        alert(nodes); // it's dispalying correct results       
        for(var i = 0; i< nodes.length; i++) 
        {
            alert(nodes.length); // correct result, no problem
            alert(nodes[i]); //correct result, no problem
            alert(nodes[i].Nodeid); // problem, value Nodeid is Undefined
            for (var idx = 0; idx < $scope.selectedNodes.length; idx++) {
                alert($scope.selectedNodes[idx].Nodeid);
                if ($scope.selectedNodes[idx].Nodeid == nodes[i].Nodeid) {
                    $scope.selectedNodes.splice(idx, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to locate the node using indexOf, which compares values using the strict '===' operator, and you're trying to compare objects.

I think it would be easier for you to use one of the many libraries outthere for collection manipulation (lodash, underscore, etc) but if you want to do it as you were doing then this is the code:

```
$scope.remove = function (nodes) {   
    angular.forEach(nodes, function (node) {                   
        for (var idx = 0; idx < $scope.selectedNodes.length; idx++) {            
            if ($scope.selectedNodes[idx].Nodeid == node.Nodeid) {
                $scope.selectedNodes.splice(idx, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

If the number of nodes to delete is very high and you're concerned about optimization then you can iterate the selectedNodes array in inverse order and be deleting the node if it's in the nodesToDelete collection. The code structure is similar, just iterating outside the selectedNodes and inside the nodesToDelete.

Comment: I am getting the value of node.Nodeid as undefined. however the value of node is {"1", "1234", "abc"}  which is what is what is expected. But how to extract nodeid out of it to compare the if statement above.

Comment: Umm, is strange... Try replacing the angular.forEach with a simple for loop and check: for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)   and instead of node.Nodeid compare with node[i].Nodeid

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. No luck with for loop too. I have added latest code in the post.

Comment: The problem seems to come from somewhere before... Check the function that creates and maintains the list of nodes to remove and look  if you're assigning correctly the Nodeid in the nodes collection, I can't see this part of the code.

Comment: The code at the very top of the page adds items to the array and the html below will display the results. Is there any problem with adding and displaying which is preventing to remove. I am passing in ng-model 'selectedItems' in the remove function

Comment: The code I'm refering is the one that construct the 'nodes' list that you pass as parameter to the $scope.remove function...

Comment: As I understand, the $scope.remove should have to remove a list of nodes from a list of selectedNodes, isn't it? This is what I can conclude from your initial question...

Comment: That's correct. A list of items which are selected need to be removed from selectedNodes( which is the complete list). I am passing in ng-model 'selectedItems'  of select tag in the remove function. Could you please have a look at select and button above. Is that the right way of passing the selected items to remove function?

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem is that value="{{node}}" in option has to be a 'value', not a reference. Try doing this: value="{ id: node.id, Nodeid: node.Nodeid, title: node.title }" wich maps the object refered to a new object.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and also value="{id: {{node.id}}, Nodeid: {{node.Nodeid}}. title: {{node.title}}}", but still the Nodeid is undefined in the remove function

Comment: Do what I told you before, but use ng-value instead of value... Sorry I didn't noticed before.

Comment: I did the same. ng-value="{id:node.id, Nodeid:node.Nodeid, title:node.title}" . I could see objects passed into the function. But the Nodeid is still undefined

Comment: But node.id and node.title are in place? Maybe you aren't assigning the Nodeid property correctly... I don't see anything more

Comment: all three, node.id, node.Nodeid and node.title are undefined. Sorry to take your time. Is there anything to be done to the select tag. And in the button ng-click, I am passing in the 'selectedItems' which is the ng-model of select. ng-model of select represent for the entire select tag, so if we try to pass in that as the parameter to ng-click, will it really pick up the selected ones only? should I need to pass something like

Comment: sorry, I did pick up the number of selected ones, but the problem is to extract the values out of it to compare. Is the select tag ok and am I doing the right thing in the ng-click of button

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong now. Maybe it's a question of scopes. I've lost perspective to your code with so many changes. Could you prepare a Codepen or similar so I can inspect more?

Comment: I think I've found the root of the problem. It's long to explain and without a Codepen or similar I can't hit the solution for your concrete scenario, but the key is in defining the options using the ngOptions directive as stated here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions I hope you can solve it. Good luck!

Comment: Just about to reply.Found the similar source. when I changed the select to <select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-options="o as o.Nodeid +' - '+ o.title for o in selectedNodes"></select>, it worked. Everything else remains the same. Thank you so much for all your help. Very grateful to you.Sorry to take your time